# The [topicname] observation buffer has not been updated for [X] seconds, and it should be updated every [Y] seconds

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to https://answers.ros.org/question/172051/base_scan-observation-buffer-has-not-been-updated/ I got this warning from `move_base`:

```
[ WARN] [1587673908.422961616]: The /camera/depth/color/points observation buffer has not been updated for 10.15 seconds, and it should be updated every 1.00 seconds.
```

When checking the the topic in question though, it was arriving at high frequency. I've solved the issue now, and will post my answer, and since it is different from the above, I think it is useful to capture it here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350426/the-%5Btopicname%5D-observation-buffer-has-not-been-updated-for-%5Bx%5D-seconds,-and-it-should-be-updated-every-%5By%5D-seconds./) by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case, the issue was that the clocks between the machine acting as ros master and the subscriber were not in sync. After syncing them back up, the warning went away and move_base accepted the point cloud data being sent.

Since there was no warning to the effect of the clock-sync issue anywhere where I could find it, I thought it useful to share this issue and resolution here.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1